# Rails Cocoon: Don't destroy the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, cocoon-gem

I've got two models. Let's name them parent and child:

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

As you can see, a parent could have many children. Now I'm using [Cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) to easily manage the associations. Now I'm having the following problem:

I want to destroy the association (in the view: `<%= link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f %>`) but not destroy the actual model. So I want to detach the child from the parent but not remove it entirely from my database. *`allow_destroy` is only in there to test everything, without it just nothing works.*

Is there any elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Similar to https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/issues/173 ?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see any relevance of that bug for my question. I do not get any error: I only want to prevent Cocoon from destroying my object.

Answer (score -2):

```
class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :parent
end
```

Comment: Uh, oh. Yeah, that's in there, too. Forgot it while writing the question. Sorry about that!

Comment: Well, it actually could have been a problem with my code. So I guess it is an answer?